# JQuery datePicker date reset

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, reset, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to add a "Reset" control to the datepicker at the bottom of the calendar - where the "close" control goes. This would enable the user to reset the input tied to datepicker to blank (no date).

I can't figure out how to write the bind function, specifically, how do I get a hold of the element bound to the control?

```
        if (this.displayClear) {
           $pop.append(
              $('<a href="#" id="dp-clear">' + $.dpText.TEXT_CLEAR + '</a>')
                 .bind(
                    'click',
                    function()
                    {
                          c.clearSelected();
                          //help! reset the value to '': $(this.something).val('')
                          c._closeCalendar();
                    }
                 )
           );
        }
```

Comment: There are some useful answers in [this discussion](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3999). See, specifically, [pfurbacher's sample implementation here](http://jsbin.com/ofare/edit).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I clear/reset the selected dates on the jQuery UI Datepicker calendar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435086/how-do-i-clear-reset-the-selected-dates-on-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-calendar)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is working solution, just call cleanDatepicker() before any call to datepicker.

```
function cleanDatepicker() {
   var old_fn = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;

   $.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) {
      old_fn.call(this, inst);

      var buttonPane = $(this).datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");

      $("<button type='button' class='ui-datepicker-clean ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all'>Delete</button>").appendTo(buttonPane).click(function(ev) {
          $.datepicker._clearDate(inst.input);
      }) ;
   }
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution... except that the button title is in Polish.  Also, I'd suggest putting this in a (function(){})(); setup, rather than creating a named function and calling it later.

Comment: In order for this to work, you have to set the datepicker option showButtonPanel to true.

Comment: Does this solution work for AJAXed buttons, that is, does that solution cause an AJAX submit to the server on clear?

Comment: How to prevent the same date input from resetting when clicking on submit? please tell
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69939209/how-to-prevent-jquery-datepicker-from-clearing-date-on-submit-in-jsp

Answer (score 19):

I found a nicer solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            showOn: 'focus',
            showButtonPanel: true,
            closeText: 'Clear', // Text to show for "close" button
            onClose: function () {
                var event = arguments.callee.caller.caller.arguments[0];
                // If "Clear" gets clicked, then really clear it
                if ($(event.delegateTarget).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
                    $(this).val('');
                }
            }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/swjw5w7q/1/

Comment: window.event is undefined in Firefox.

Comment: Not working with latest version https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 9):

This Will Add Clear Button On Jquery Calender That Will Clear Date.

```
 $("#txtDOJ").datepicker({
     showButtonPanel: true,
     closeText: 'Clear',
     onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
         if ($(window.event.srcElement).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
             document.getElementById(this.id).value = '';
         }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Change the Done label to Clear and add code to clear

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#startdate").datepicker({
           showOn: 'both',
           buttonImageOnly: true,
           buttonImage: "css/images/calendar.gif",
           showButtonPanel: true,
           closeText: 'Clear',
           onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
               $(this).val('');
           }
       });
   });
   ```
2. Add Clear button to the calendar (pros: users who are used to standard jQuery-UI Calendar won't confuse the Clear button for Close)

   ```
   function addClearBtnToCalendar(inst) {
       setTimeout(function () {
           var buttonPane = $(inst).datepicker("widget")
               .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
           var btn = $('<button class="ui-datepicker-current'
                + ' ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all"'
                + ' type="button">Clear</button>');
           btn.unbind("click").bind("click", function () {
                $.datepicker._clearDate(inst.input);
           });
           btn.appendTo(buttonPane);
       }, 1);
   }

   $("#termdate").datepicker({
       showOn: 'both',
       buttonImageOnly: true,
       buttonImage: "css/images/calendar.gif",
       showButtonPanel: true,
       beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
           addClearBtnToCalendar(inst);
       },
       onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
           addClearBtnToCalendar(inst);
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: 2. The Clear button disappears when you change a month or click Today.

Answer (score 3):

I was going through this same problem, that is, no option available to empty the datepicker. I then found this super useful comment with a sweet piece of code posted [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3999#comment:21):

One quick way you can add the clear feature even on read only fields is to add the following code to your existing datepicker control:

```
}).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
        $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
    }
});
```

This will enable people to highlight (which they can even on Read Only fields) and then use the backspace or delete to remove the date using the internal `_clearDate` function.

Comment: That's ok if you ignore the mobile/tablet users

Comment: In my testing, using the backspace button like this in a readOnly field triggers the back button in chrome and ie. However, the delete works great. You still get +1 because the read only functionality isn't part of the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the scoop

We can use default done button to bind a custom clear function.

```
$("#date_picker").datepicker({minDate:myDate,dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',showButtonPanel:true,closeText:'Clear',
    beforeShow: function( input ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
        var clearButton = $(input )
            .datepicker( "widget" )
            .find( ".ui-datepicker-close" );
        clearButton.unbind("click").bind("click",function(){$.datepicker._clearDate( input );});
        }, 1 );
    }
});
```

Works like a charm. Cheers :);)

credits: Sébastien Renauld and BehranG BinA

Comment: @Sébastien Renauld clear button will not be available if you shuffle months. checkout [link](http://jsbin.com/ofare/451/edit)