# reset jquery ui datepicker's minDate maxDate upon deletion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two datepickers for a date range selection, it works same as the demo on jquery UI's demo page, however, when a user actually manually deletes the date field value, I  need to reset the other date field to how it was initially. I tried to write the code below, but for some odd reason, whenever I select a date in the `from` calendar, it shows up in the `to` field and the minDate/maxDate settings don't seem to work at all.

```
$( "#dt_from" ).blur(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="")
        {
            $( "#dt_to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", "+0" );
        }
    }).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+0d",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/Cal.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate:+0,
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#dt_to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $( "#dt_to" ).blur(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="")
        {
            $( "#dt_from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", "" );
        }
    }).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+0d",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/Cal.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate:+0,
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#dt_from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
```

I believe the blur event is somehow causing this mess, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah thanks to another post here [How do I clear/reset the selected dates on the jQuery UI Datepicker calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435086/jquery-ui-datepicker-how-do-i-clear-reset-the-datepicker-calendar) I figured out how to solve this. I am posting the code here for future reference.

```
$( "#dt_from" ).prop("readonly",true).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+0d",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/Cal.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate:+0,
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            if(selectedDate!="")
            {
                $( "#dt_to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            }
        }
    }).keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
            $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
            $( "#dt_to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", "today" );
        }
    });
    $( "#dt_to" ).prop("readonly",true).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+0d",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/Cal.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate:+0,
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            if(selectedDate!="")
            {
                $( "#dt_from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
            }
        }
    }).keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
            $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
            $( "#dt_from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", "" );
        }
    });
```

I made the fields readonly just to be safe, and then within the del/bkspace key check I reset the options.