# jQuery UI datepicker reset date

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, datepicker

I have a `datepicker` that's on an input field, default date when I first open it is today's date, which is what I want.
However, when I select a date and I clear the input field, the `datepicker` still has the selected date on it, which I don't want

Does anyone have an idea why this happens and how I can prevent this behavior?

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: What do you mean by select a date and clear input field ? is is that you are directly clearing input field without invoking datepicker on that field and clearing it ?

Comment: Use $.datepicker._clearDate(this); in here this is your input field

Comment: would you have just read datepicker's manual? if not check http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435086/jquery-ui-datepicker-how-do-i-clear-reset-the-datepicker-calendar and try http://jsfiddle.net/tF5MH/9/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See http://codepen.io/alexgill/pen/yOQrwV

```
$(SELECTOR).datepicker('setDate', null);
```

Comment: exactly, _ API is always private

Comment: That's great, but the year doesn't reset

Comment: So I ended up doing $(SELECTOR).datepicker('setDate', new Date()); and then $(SELECTOR).datepicker('setDate', null); to get the year reset as well

Answer (score 37):

The proper way to reset the date of a Datepicker widget is like this:

```
$.datepicker._clearDate('#input_field_goes_here');
```

Or like this:

```
$('#input_field_goes_here').datepicker('setDate', null);
```

Whichever works best for you.

Comment: The second one is the more official answer. Using the private API is a bad idea.

Comment: Agreed.  The second one is the best one.

Answer (score 7):

Clear button in calendar.

```
 $("#txtCalendar").datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        closeText: 'Clear',
        onClose: function (dateText, obj) {
            if ($(window.event.srcElement).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close'))
                $("#txtCalendar").val('');
        }
    });
```

Comment: great but changed $("#txtCalendar").val(''); to $(this).val(''); for multiple instances

Comment: @BarryDowd This looks clever. However I get `window.event is undefined` (at least in Firefox). Any workaround? Thanks!

Comment: @SeaBass the example is using a deprecated reference (`window.event.srcElement`), in order to make it work, you need to replace it with `event.target`. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code

```
}).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
        $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
    }
});
```

You can use backspace to clear field even if it has in read only mode. [Source](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3999#comment:21)

Comment: I had to use `$( dateInput ).attr( "value", null )` instead of `_clearDate`.

Answer (score 0):

To really reset everything, including the selected year in the date selector popup, I had to do the following:

```
$(SELECTOR).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
$(SELECTOR).datepicker('setDate', null);
```

Just doing the last line results in the previously selected year to show in the date selector