# Reset and keep the dates as default dates in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

My HTML code

```
<div style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">
    <label for="fromDateRange">From:</label>
    <div id="fromDateRange"></div>
</div>

<div style="margin-left:20px; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">
    <label for="toDateRange">Till:</label>
    <div id="toDateRange"></div>
</div>
```

My javascript:-

```
$('#toDateRange').datepicker({
    // minDate: $( "#fromDateRange" ).datepicker( "getDate" ),
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear:true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#fromDateRange" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
    }
});


$( "#fromDateRange").datepicker({
     defaultDate: "-1m",
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear:true,
     numberOfMonths: 1,
     dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
     onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
         $( "#toDateRange" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    }
});
```

clear dates function:

```
function clearDates() {
    clear="";
    $('#dateFilter').val(clear);
    $("#dateFilter").trigger("change");
    $('#date-range').hide();        
}
```

Once I clear the active dates in the date picker should be the default one.How Do I do it?

Comment: To get you right... you want a user to select a date that's set as default when `clearDates` is called ?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435086/jquery-ui-datepicker-how-do-i-clear-reset-the-datepicker-calendar

Comment: Dwza You are right. . That is what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right and you really want to set a date as default when the user uses `clearDates()` you have to store the Informations that was given.

For this you have to ways...

**Way One (LocalStorage):**

```
//set value to browser cache
    localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
//get from browser cache
    localStorage.getItem("key"); //returns the setted value
//remove specific entry from browser cache
    localStorage.removeItem("key"); //delete entry xy
//remove all from browser cache
    localStorage.clear();
```

**Way two:**

Use cookys.