# Clear Date Selection using Primefaces Calendar

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is there any way to clear the date selection using prime faces calendar?

```
<p:calendar pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" navigator="true" id="endDate" for="endDate"
readonlyInput="true" mindate="#{manageMarketingProgramsBean.currentDate}" showOn="button">
<f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" timeZone="America/New_York" />
</p:calendar>
```

I have readonlyInput="true" because I dont want user to type the date. I force them to pick the date from the calendar, there needs to be another way to provide user the ability to clear the date selected. Please let me know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

The first approach that comes into my mind would be:

```
<p:calendar readonlyInput="true" widgetVar="calendarWidget"/>     
<p:commandButton value="Reset" onclick="calendarWidget.setDate(null)"/>
```

Comment: Will this button be displayed next to the calendar? Is there way to add to the calendar itself either button or link?

Comment: Yes, it is just an additional button that sets the value of the calendar value to null by using calendar's javascript client api. You could also use plain html: `<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="calendarWidget.setDate(null);"/>`.

Comment: Since PrimeFaces p:calendar is an implementation of jQuery Datepicker, then see the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917779/jquery-datepicker-date-reset

Comment: Unfortunately, the above solution doesn't seem to work with AJAXed p:calendars, that is, if the calendar has a p:ajax tag, no AJAX request is issued when the reset button is executed. See followup question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14235357/396732

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
<p:calendar widgetVar="calendarWidget" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />     
<p:commandButton value="Reset" onclick="PF('calendarWidget').setDate(null)" 
type="button" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Primefaces for the calendar component have this property: showButtonBar.

If you set it to true like this:

```
          <p-calendar
            appendTo="body"
            formControlName="someControl"
            id="someID"
            [maxDate]="someMaxDate"
            [showButtonBar]="true"
            [showIcon]="true"
          ></p-calendar>
```

Then it will display two buttons on the calendar component. Today and Clear.

Hope it helps somebody.

[image]

Comment: tested and this works nicely for primeNG version 13.0.4

Answer (score 0):

> HTML

```
<p:calendar 
    yearRange="c-100:c+100" 
    readonlyInput="true" 
    pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" 
    id="identity" 
    navigator="true" 
    mindate="today" 
    widgetVar="dateWidget" 
    value="#{bean.fieldname}" 
/>
```

> JS

```
function name() {
    var mainID = prefix + collpaseID;
    -
      -
        -
          -
    clearCalendar(mainID,event);
}



function clearCalendar(collapseId) {
    try {
            allElements = 
 document.getElementById(collapseId).getElementsByClassName('hasDatepicker');

        for (i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; ++i) {
            allElements[i].setAttribute('onkeyup', 
'clearDate("'+allElements[i].id+'", event)');
        }
    }
    catch(e) {}
}



function clearDate(fieldID, e) {
    try{
        // 8 - backspace key, 46 - delete key
        if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
            //PF(getWidgetVarById(collapseId)).setDate(null);
            document.getElementById(fieldID).value="";
        }
    }
    catch(e){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:calendar
    widgetVar="calendarWidgetStart"
/>

<p:calendar
    widgetVar="calendarWidgetEnd"
/>

<p:commandLink
    value="Action"
    action="#{entity.action}"
    onclick="setTimeout('remoteCommand();', 100);"
/>

<p:remoteCommand
    name="remoteCommand"
    update="@form"
    onstart="clearCalendarWidget();"
/>

<script>
    function clearCalendarWidget() { 
        $( PF('calendarWidgetEnd').setDate(null) ); 
        $( PF('calendarWidgetStart').setDate(null) );
    } 
</script>
```