# Select NULL date using jQueryUI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker

I am using the jQueryUI datepicker along with the datetime addon (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#basic_examples).  I am using an icon to trigger opening up the calender instead of an input field.  Is it possible to configure the plugin so that the user has the ability to clear the date (or in other words, select NULL as the date) and not just select a date?  If so, how?  Thank you

Comment: Isn't it a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917779/jquery-datepicker-date-reset ?  But this is too broad question, there is too many solutions possible, i guess... You should instead try something on your side and, if stuck somewhere, ask relevant question regarding your issue

Comment: @A.Wolff  Thank you for your comment.  If there is some built-in option to do so, I don't think it is too broad, but yea if there isn't, it is a bit too broad.  Your recommended link definitely provides some ideas.  Thanks again.